# Kusto: Permission based display of columns

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to access function parameters within the 'case' statement in that function and displaying data/"filtered" based on the permission flag..Is it possible?

**Usecase:** TypeCast the value based on the columnType and check if the user has the permission to view the column based on which you display either the value or say something like "filtered" 
Here is what I tried

**function rls_columnCheck**

```
.create-or-alter function rls_columnCheck(tableName:string, columnName: string, value:string, columnType:string, IsInGroupPII:bool, IsInGroupFinance:bool) {
    let PIIColumns = rls_getTablePermissions(tableName, "PII");
    let FinanceColumns = rls_getTablePermissions(tableName, "Finance");

    let val= case(columnType=="bool", tobool(value),
                  columnType=="datetime", todatetime(value),
                  columnType=="int", toint(value),
                  value);

    iif(columnName in (PIIColumns), 
        iif(columnName in (FinanceColumns), 
            iif(IsInGroupPII == true and IsInGroupFinance == true, 
                val, 
                "filtered"), // PII True, Fin True
            iif(IsInGroupPII == true, 
                val, 
                "filtered") // PII True, Fin False
        ), 
        iif(columnName in (FinanceColumns), 
            iif(IsInGroupFinance == true, 
                val, 
                "filtered"), // PII False, Fin True
            val // PII False, Fin False
        )
    );    
}
```

**Error:**

```
Call to iff(): @then data type (int) must match the @else data type (string)
```

Answer (score 0):

`val` in your function must have a single and well-defined data type, that is known at "compile" time of the query.
you can't have different cases, where in each it has a *different* type (`bool`, `datetime`, `int`, `string` - in your `case` statement) - hence the error.

if it makes sense in your use case, you can try to always have `val` typed as `string`.

Comment: RLS doesn't change the type of the column, it must be something else you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good approach to use RLS because this will actually cause the engine to run a function for every column of every record. It has many downsides:

- Performance of displaying the table’s contents (even if you have full permissions)
- Queries on the table won’t benefit from the indexes Kusto stores (suppose you query `PermissionTesting2 | where Col1 has “blablabla”` - instead of checking the index for “blablabla”, the engine will have to scan all the data, because it has to apply a function for every single cell)

A better approach is to do something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/rowlevelsecuritypolicy#expose-different-data-to-members-of-different-azure-ad-groups):

```
let UserCanSeePII = current_principal_is_member_of('aadgroup=group1@domain.com');
let UserCanSeeFinance = current_principal_is_member_of('aadgroup=group2@domain.com');
let ResultWithPII = YourTable | where UserCanSeePII and (not UserCanSeeFinance) | where ... | extend ...;
let ResultWithFinance = YourTable | where UserCanSeeFinance and (not UserCanSeePII) | where ... | extend ...;
let ResultWithPIIandFinance = YourTable | where UserCanSeeFinance and UserCanSeePII | where ... | extend ...;
let ResultWithoutPIIandFinance = YourTable | where (not UserCanSeePII) and (not UserCanSeeFinance) | where ... | extend ...;
union ResultWithPII, ResultWithFinance, ResultWithPIIandFinance, ResultWithoutPIIandFinance
```